# How can I tell dropbox to not login automatically?

Tags: dropbox

I installed Dropbox on my Windows machine, and when I first launched it, it asked me to enter my username and password. There was no checkbox asking whether I want Dropbox to remember my username and password, so I assume it is remembered by default. Is there a way to change this default behaviour so that Dropbox does not login automatically when I log into my account?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.  The only thing that comes close is stopping Drop Box from starting automatically with your computer:

- Right click the Dropbox status tray icon
- Click the gear symbol at the top right
- Click preferences
- Uncheck Start Dropbox on system startup

Answer (score 0):

You can simply download the files you need through their website and it won't remember you.

also this is maybe useful:

To "forget" your account on your machine -- right click the Dropbox icon in the task tray --> Preferences --? Account --> Unlink This Computer. (SnakeDoc.)